How does ObservableCollection/INotifyPropertyChange work when object is changed
I have a situation where in one view model some properties on an object are updated. In another view model, I subscribe to a message and then update a collection with this new object, e.g.:
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<UpdatedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    if (this.MyObjects != null)
    {
        var myObj = this.MyObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyObject == m.Value.MyObject);

        if (myObj != null)
        {
            myObj = m.Value;
            //myObj.MyProperty = m.Value.MyProperty; //this updates UI, above line does not
        }
    }
});

Even though MyObject implements INotifyPropertyChanged and MyObjects is an ObservableCollection<MyObject> the WPF UI does not update.
However, if I update a property on myObj like this:
myObj.MyProperty = m.Value.MyProperty;
The WPF UI does update.
I assume this is because changing the object doesn't trigger the PropertyChanged event (because it's neither an Add/Update/Reorder on the collection), unlike changing a property on the object.
So two questions:

Is my understanding of why this doesn't work correct?
What is the best way to handle this situation where any/all properties might have changed? I want to avoid having to manually write updates for each property on the object (which would then break if a new property is added and I forget to update this message receipt).


I don't see a change to the mentioned object in your code so no event is fired.

You presumably need to exchange the object in MyObjects not just change the instance myObj points to.

Yes, that's what I've deduced. var myObj is a reference to an object in the collection. When I do myObj = m.Value; I'm changing the local variables reference object, not updating the object in the collection. So my question was how do I achieve the update to all properties on the object in the collection, without having to write it out for each object.

When the collection is an ObservableCollection, you can replace myObj by m.Value. You do however need to find its index, int index = MyObjects.IndexOf(myObj);. Then write MyObjects[index] = m.Value;

If the order of elements does not matter, write MyObjects.Remove(myObj); MyObjects.Add(m.Value);

I did try the Add/Remove option but because it changed the order it kinda messed things up on the UI side. I didn't think about replacing it by index, I'll try that.

Okay yeah, using the IndexOf worked. Thanks. If you want to write an answer I'll mark as accepted.

Instead of calling MyObjects.FirstOrDefault followed by MyObjects.IndexOf, you may want to find the index directly by means of a simple for or while loop.

The expression
myObj = m.Value;

only changes the value of a local variable, and is hence not updating the UI.
You would have to replace the object in the MyObjects collection, maybe most efficiently by means of a simple for loop:
if (MyObjects != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MyObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (MyObjects[i].MyProperty == m.Value.MyProperty)
        {
            MyObjects[i] = m.Value;
            break;
        }
    }
}

